# Regex to match invalid JSON strings

Tags: regex, json

I want to use a regex search to match invalid JSON containing name/value pairs where the name is not in quotes.  Example:

Invalid (I'm trying to match this):

```
{name:"value"}
```

Valid (I'll fix 'em to look like so):

```
{"name":"value"}
```

What RegEx can I use to best match an object key that **does not** contain "" double quotes? (Single quotes are ok to match, as I will want to convert those to double quotes anyway).

Comment: why not try to parse the JSON and see if it works?

Comment: Updated the question with more context.

Comment: Don't use a regex. Use a JSON parser. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 2):

In general in regex, when you want to indicate `not` you use the `^` character. For instance, in the example a regex string to match anything other than a quote would look like this:

```
r'\{[ \t]+[^\"]*[a-zA-Z]+[^\"][ \t]+:'
```

Of course, this will probably fail in a number of cases as regex is NOT the right choice for this problem. You should just try to parse it and throw an error if it doesn't work. In python:

```
import json

try:
    json.loads(attempt)
except ValueError:
    print "INVALID JSON"
    raise
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt... but that didn't seem to work for me.  i'm trying to use this regex in a file search to weed out the files i need to update.  and unfortunately, it's not really conducive to attempting the json.loads() function either, as I first need to determine which files even contain JSON.

Comment: @anthony The files that end with .json are the ones that contain json. It is also absolutely conducive to use json.loads(). It also seems that you're asking a totally different question here than in your question. I suggest you update your question and provide samples because determining the validity of json is easy, determining if an arbitrary file was some failed **attempt** at json rather than YAML, or some other similar format is a very different problem.

Comment: We do not use .json files for reasons I won't explain. To be frank, my original question literally asked what I literally wanted to know: I wanted a RegEx to match the text patterns I indicated. I respectfully moved on from your first response because I tried it and found that it did not return any results, but as a consequence, you have unfairly down-voted my question and my suggested solution. I did not ask you to make assumptions about the purpose for my question.  And, with respect, I do not think it was as terrible a question as you are making it out to be.

Comment: @anthony I don't mean to be disparaging, but the simple fact that you answered the "literal" question that you asked and it didn't solve your problem means that you asked the wrong question. You yourself admitted that your solution was completely unhelpful to you and have cryptically alluded to many more constraints elsewhere. If you would simply explain the **entirety** of your predicament I'm sure you would find us much more willing and able to assist. The downvote also didn't come from me, but I agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

JSON needs to be parsed, to properly find out if it is valid. You can use the [jison json parser example](https://github.com/zaach/jison/blob/master/examples/json.js), and change the rules to account for your additional valid JSON case. However, it gets much, much harder to parse a JSON blob if you remove the quote requirement from the keys.

I suggest you leave the grammer the same, and add some [error handling rules](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_9.html#SEC81)(alpha support unfortunately). This is a complex problem, so take the time to research before diving in and you'll be much better off.

Answer (score 0):

just replace `\{\s*(?!(\"|\'))(\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*)(?!(\"|\'))\s*:(.+)` with `{"$2" :$4` and you will get no variable will be without ' or " :)

Answer (score -2):

Well, this worked for me, as I needed to match strings that would pass for valid javascript variable names, with allowance for single quotes on either side (and I also threw in an allowance for spaces on either side).

```
\{+( |')?+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*+( |')?+:
```

I'm still wrapping my head around regex, but my understand is, this expression will match strings that...

1. start with {
2. then, may or may not have a space or single quote
3. then, have any number of characters matching a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _
4. then, may or may not have a space or single quote
5. then, have a :

However, this also ended up matching all manner of CSS, jQuery functions, and other non-JSON strings (at least not the true JSON responses I was looking for)... for instance, things like `{display:none}` and `$(...).animate({'height':'200px'})`. Too many results to be usable for my purposes. Ah well!

Comment: `{display:none}` is in fact not valid JSON. If the exact thing you asked for didn't meet your requirements you should probably explain what you are actually trying to do in your question so that people can help you.